# How to identify coupling between types due to typeof composition using NDepend API's?

Tags: c#, .net, ndepend

How can I identify the dependencies between the two types only due to typeof composition using **NDepend rules/API**.

In the below example the type is dependent on *UsedDependendType* only through *typeof(UsedDependendType)*, no other members are involved in the coupling.

```
class OnlyTypeOfDependencyBetweenTypes
{
    public IEnumerable<Type> Initialize()
    {
        return new List<Type> {
            typeof(UsedDependendType)
        };
    }
}
```

I am able to identify whether there are any members involved in the dependency between these types. But for confirming I need to know whether there is a call to typeof(UsedDependendType) is there or not.

Using NDepend API/CQL how can I identify the call **typeof(UsedDependendType)** in a method?

Regards
Basanth

Answer (score 0):

For now there is no way to segregate `typeof(TUsed)` over other usages.

You can try and maybe refine this query that list pairs of types `(t,tUsed)` where there is no member involved in the dependency.

```
from t in Application.Types
// No typeof() in interface
where !t.IsInterface

from tUsed in t.TypesUsed
// Don't count third-party
where !tUsed.IsThirdParty
// Don't count tUsed when it is an attribute
where !tUsed.IsAttributeClass
where !t.Implement(tUsed)

// Don't enumerate both (A,B) and (B,A)
where string.Compare(tUsed.Name, t.Name) < 0

// tUsed is not used as a return type nor a field type
where !t.Methods.WithReturnType(tUsed).Any()
where !t.Fields.WithFieldType(tUsed).Any()

// No member of tUsed is used by t
where !tUsed.Members.UsedByAny(t.Methods).Any()

select new { t, tUsed }
```

Comment: I tried the approach suggested, i.e. by filtering all other cases except typeof(Type) dependency. This works most use cases except for the following,

1. Method return type including the TUsed type in an IEnumerable (IEnumerable<UsedDependendType>) is not identified by t.Methods.WithReturnType(tUsed).Any().
2. Unable to find a way to detect method parameters containing the used type.
3. Unable to find a way to detect constructor parameters containing the used type.